# flow rate through a propeller disc

Tags: propeller

Let's take the case of a stock Cessna 150, chained to the ground, standard day conditions. The engine is running at full power (say 2500RPM) and the propeller is absorbing its full output. Is there a formula that allows the calculation of the volumetric rate of flow of air through the propeller disc for this static test case?

Comment: [This answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/8822/62) might be relevant

Comment: thanks @pondlife, that is most excellent!

Comment: I am also surprised that you replied before our friend Peter Kaempf!

Comment: Chained to the ground, I didn't know that a C150 prop could absorb full output of the power plant.

Comment: aviation humor detected!