# Is it possible to build a turbojet engine with aluminum cans? (Soft drink cans)

Tags: turbofan

I'm interested in building a working model of a turbojet engine, but I don't have a lot of supplies. So I'm wondering if it's possible to use aluminum cans for construction, for every body part. While we're on this topic, would the heat melt the aluminum?

Comment: See [What material is used to make the hot sections of jet engines?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/25645/what-material-is-used-to-make-the-hot-sections-of-jet-engines/25647#25647). A model will still have high-temperature and high-pressure areas.

Comment: There was a junkyard wars episode where a team made a jet engine out of scrap metal, and it worked long enough to win the competition. Pretty epic and worth a look. I don't think aluminum soft drink cans are up to the task but there's other scrap material which could be used.

Comment: What materials do you recommend?

Comment: How about a pulse jet? They're supposedly much simpler to build.
http://www.pulsejetengines.com/how-to-make-a-pulse-jet/

Comment: @XTImpossible materials should be something with a high melting point. Steel might work for a short period... also suggestion by ROIMaison is a very good one...

Comment: Visit a junkyard and find an old turbocharger?

Comment: @ROIMaison Holy smokes, not a single disclaimer on that whole page! Hope the plans have the address of their attorney on them.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Melt point of aluminum is 660.3 °C

Comment: How are you going to make the axis just from cans?

Comment: Cut the top and bottom of the can and roll the side up to form a stick?

Comment: Although i'm generally talking about a small engine the size of a water bottle. I checked the article, I prefer to build a turbojet engine.

Comment: Maybe a jet engine isn't something that should be built on a whim when short on supplies? Why can't you get actual materials and do it properly?

Comment: Because it's more challenging this way.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot make an entire model jet engine out of aluminium.
Most fuels burn at 1000+C and aluminium melts at around 660C: Even if you keep the burning contained in airflow (thus away from the walls) the heat transfer will still damage the aluminium.

You could make the majority of the engine from it, though: Just as long as you find something more suitable for the 'hot' parts.

Comment: A quick Google search turned up that you can burn an Ethanol-water mixture at 700K (427 degrees C). And you might be able to wrap the fuel supply lines around the combustion chamber to preheat the fuel and simultaneously cool the chamber. Still, that first disk in the turbine will be running hot.