# Are flame holders made of a special material other than that used in combustion chamber?

Tags: jet-engine, aerospace-materials, propulsion, fluid-mechanics, combustion

Are the flame holders made of materials which have higher friction coefficients than the combustion chamber in order to create turbulence?

Comment: Additional information about materials: [What material is used to make the hot sections of jet engines?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/25645/what-material-is-used-to-make-the-hot-sections-of-jet-engines)

Answer (score 2):

In [The Jet Engine](https://books.google.com/books?id=QUQxBwAAQBAJ), there is no mention of a two-material setup for the flame-holder/combustor. It's all about the design of the diffuser and combustor shape / holes.

One of the fancy things they mention (p. 122, image below) is the lining of the walls in elevated ceramic-coated tiles for internal cooling.

[image]

Having to deal with two materials would decrease the structural integrity of the combuster. And to my knowledge, the [flame-holder and combustor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combustor) are one and the same, a single unit.