# Is platinum present in a combustion chamber?

Tags: aircraft-design

Platinum group of metals (PGM) are very resistant to extreme heat. Why is platinum never mentioned in aerospace world? Is this a top secret?

Comment: Related: [What material is used to make the hot sections of jet engines?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/25645/) Density (Pt = 21.45, Ni = 8.91) and cost limit the use of platinum (and more overall, so called platinum group metals, PGM), see [this article](http://www.technology.matthey.com/pdf/112-119-pmr-apr10.pdf).

Comment: Use of platinum & iridium in spark plugs is quite common, so it's not true that the use is never mentioned.  E.g. http://www.championaerospace.com/products/spark-plugs

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on mins comment: platinum right now is selling for around \$1000 / troy ounce, which is ~\$14,500 / pound.  Nickel is selling for around \$4 / pound and cobalt is \$25/pound. [Nickel and cobalt super alloys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superalloy) have sufficient temperature capability for jet engine applications.  So the choice is clear. Platinum is not mentioned because it is not used.