# Can liquid hydrogen be pumped directly into a jet engine without a heat exchanger? Is it burned as a gas or a liquid in the combustion chamber?

Tags: jet-engine, aircraft-systems, engine, engine-design, hydrogen

[This NASA research paper](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4404/contents.htm) on H<sub>2</sub> engines includes a diagram of Wesley Kuhrt's 1956 design for a hydrogen-fuelled engine, which has no heat exchanger:

[image: LH2 engine sans heat exchanger]

(Image by United Technologies Corporation, via [NASA](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4404/ch8-7.htm).)

But, later on, it also has two diagrams showing hydrogen-fuelled engines *with* heat exchangers for warming the hydrogen before use; first, a Pratt & Whitney JT3C (J57) modified to burn hydrogen instead of kerosene:

[image: hydrogen-fuelled JT3C]

(Image by Pratt & Whitney, via [NASA](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4404/ch8-8.htm).)

followed by the Pratt & Whitney 304, an engine designed from the start to run on hydrogen:

[image: P&W 304, running on hydrogen, with the heat exchanger]

(Image by Pratt & Whitney, via [NASA](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4404/ch8-9.htm).)

In a jet engine using liquid hydrogen for fuel, does the hydrogen have to be warmed (presumably using a heat exchanger) and converted to a gas before it can be introduced into the combustion chamber, or can it be pumped in and burned straight as a liquid?

Comment: Please [edit] to put the question in the actual question, not just the title.  Also, the image is too small to see well, can you link a larger copy?

Comment: [Closely related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/73629/62), maybe a dupe?

Comment: Also, please cite the full details of the NASA paper.

Comment: In order to mix with oxygen and burn, hydrogen **must** be gaseous. If it is injected as a liquid, it must evaporate first, needing a longer combustion chamber.

Comment: And what did the NASA research paper say or not say specifically that led to you asking this question?

Comment: i have added the research paper pls check. in that one its mentioning a heat exchanger through which h2 flowing. i think like sabre engine

Answer (score 3):

Hydrogen has to be in gaseous state to burn. The boiling point of hydrogen is ~20 kelvins, while oxygen boils at about 90 kelvins and freezes to solid at ~54 kelvins. It is therefore impossible to mix these two for combustion if hydrogen is in liquid state.

A non scientific answer to pumping liquid hydrogen directly to the combustion chamber is, that it will not work, because the evaporization of hydrogen would bind too much energy from the compressed air, thus cooling it and lowering the pressure to a state that no longer can support efficient combustion.

However, as elements might work in surpising ways under pressure, I'm not 100% sure.