# What material is used to make engine covers for passenger airliners?

Tags: jet-engine, airliner, commercial-aviation, engine

What material is used to make the engine shrouds for passenger airliners?

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE! I've edited out the extra words in your question, in order to make it clearer. But you can revert back to the original version if you want. : )

Comment: If you mean material for the casing, then  aluminum or polymer matrix materials, see [What material is used to make the hot sections of jet engines?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/25645/3201)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are potentially two answers to this question

If you are asking about [engine covers used to keep debris out](http://www.aircraftspruce.com/catalog/pspages/jetenginecovers.php) when the aircraft is parked like these

[image]

([source](http://www.aircraftspruce.com/catalog/pspages/jetenginecovers.php))

They are made out of any manner of fabric, nylon, canvas and often foam filled if they are inserted somewhere.

If you are asking about the exterior housing around an engine its generally aluminum like the rest of the aircraft. Much like the open panels that can be seen here.

[image]

([source](http://imgproc.airliners.net/photos/airliners/8/4/3/0325348-v40-6.jpg))

Comment: The fan cowls in your second picture are usually aluminum, but composites can also be involved, especially for the thrust reversers.

Comment: Engine cowlings are composite on anything half-modern, not aluminum. Some versions of the 737 use composite, as well as 757/767 forward. All the engine cowlings on Airbuses are composite.

Comment: Most of the aluminum in modern engine cowlings (what you call housings) is in the honeycomb sandwich cores.

Comment: What specific material are Water Vapour Resistant (WVR) engine bags made from?