# Why does the CF6 have a lower bypass ratio than the TF39?

Tags: turbofan, engine-design, bypass-ratio

The [General Electric TF39](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Electric_TF39), which powered the original C-5 Galaxy, was the very first high-bypass turbofan brought into mass production, with a previously unheard-of 8:1 bypass ratio.  Yet, when it came time to make a civilian version of the TF39 (what would become known as the [General Electric CF6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Electric_CF6)), GE cranked the bypass ratio back to under 6:1 for the lowest-thrust version, and to 5.31:1 or lower for the beefier CF6s.

Why did GE *decrease* the bypass ratio of their engine, rather than increasing it further?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Increasing the bypass actually decreases the thrust. A good example is the CFM56-5B variant ([sortable table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CFM_International_CFM56#CFM56-5B_series) on Wikipedia). The reason is easy to grasp, the more air bypasses the core, the lower the core's power.

The next question would be how did the TF39 achieve higher bpr *and* thrust? Through an extra half-fan and extra turbine stage. It will make sense by viewing the cross section drawing and front view below:

[image]
([flightglobal.com](https://www.flightglobal.com/pdfarchive/view/1969/1969%20-%200475.html)) CF6 top half, TF39 bottom half.

[image]
([wikimedia.org](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:USAF_C-5_Galaxy_Engine.jpg)) TF39 front view.

This covers the thrust/bpr and the how, on to **the why.** The DC-10 (the launch CF6 customer) cruised at a higher Mach number (M0.82-0.88) compared to the Galaxy's M0.77. At high Mach numbers, a lower bpr is more efficient (think turboprop with a 40:1 bpr and a jet) -- speed is the key here.

Other reasons include the airlines' desire to have *one* fan with easy access, and fewer parts to deal with. *Flight* summarized it [in 1969](https://www.flightglobal.com/pdfarchive/view/1969/1969%20-%200475.html) as follows:

> *General Electric CF6* in -6 form at 40,000 lb thrust for take-oft was the engine specified by American Airlines and United Air Lines in their launching orders for the DC-10-10. Whereas the TF39 has a large two-stage front fan assembly the CF6-6 has an entirely new single-stage fan with a small single-stage booster fan. The change brings down the by-pass ratio from 8.0 to 6.2 and permits the deletion of a stage from the compressor; take-off thrust is reduced from 41,000 lb (TF39) to 39,400 lb (CF6-6) but the cruise thrust/s.f.c. characteristics are improved at higher Mach. Other changes include fan blade containment built-in to the casing; substitution of a gearbox to suit airline requirements; control system adapted to airline practice (idle and reverse added); increased accessibility of fan and gearbox; external piping; and a review of all materials for increased life.

The beefier CF6 you mention -- the CF6-50 -- again increased the airflow reaching the core (which reduces the bypass air) by adding booster stages behind the fan. This is how to get higher thrust with minimal changes.

[image]
([flightglobal.com](https://www.flightglobal.com/pdfarchive/view/1969/1969%20-%200475.html))