# What's the more accepted notation used to label sensors present in turbo-jet engines?

Tags: flight-controls, fadec

I'm interested in learning what the proper (more accepted) notation used to label sensors present in turbo-jet engines is.

Came across a few examples such the ones shown below but would like to learn if there is a 'standardized' methodology.

[image: temperature and pressure notation]
[Temperature and pressure notation](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Temperature-and-pressure-notation-of-a-typical-turbo-jet-engine-Picture-courtesy-of_fig2_6549209)

[image: speed notation][Speed Notation](https://www.slideshare.net/egajunior/trent-1000-presentation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sensors are identified in your picture by either P or T, for pressure or temperature, and the engineering station number.

Station numbering is standardized in [SAE ARP 755](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/9780470774533.app1): *SAE Aerospace Recommended Practice 755 - Turbine Engine Performance Station Numbering*. As you find yourself this standard has been extended to *SAE AS 755 - Aircraft Propulsion System Performance Station Designation* to take into account more complex engines

The main stations for a turbojet are:

[image]

Additional stations are used, e.g. for a turbofan. :

[image]

[Source](https://www.gasturb.com/software/gasturb/cycle-design.html).

These numbers are used, for example, in this [temperature-entropy diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperature%E2%80%93entropy_diagram):

[image]

[Source](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/tjj.2018.35.issue-3/tjj-2017-0053/tjj-2017-0053.xml?lang=en).

You can see the raise of temperature by the combustor between {3} and {4}. See [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/34600/3201) for explanations.

Comment: ARP755 has been superseded by AS755F [https://www.sae.org/standards/content/as755f/ ]

Comment: @user67034: Good find, I edited my answer to include this extension.