# Exhaust temperature of CFM56 engines range (Nozzle downstream temp)?

Tags: jet-engine, aircraft-physics, turbofan, engine-design

EGT is available but not the temp of the exhaust nozzle in the CFM56 series.

Comment: EGT is T49.5. Which engineering station are you looking for? T8? T9? Which CFM56 model?

Comment: @mins Are you adhering to the AS755 standard (Aircraft Propulsion System Performance Station Designation and Nomenclature)? Please do, we have created these  standards to communicate clearly about positions in the gas path (although sometimes even OEMs don't). Note that 3 digit (or 4) station numbering is now common, 49.5 is located in the turbomachinery according to the standard numbering (while it should have been 0495), the EGT starts after the last turbine exit (mechanical expansion process) which is station 050.

Comment: @Setare how far downstream are you looking at?

Comment: Turbofan engines CFM56 series.

Comment: My question is the Temperature downstream of the LPT and exhaust Temp from the nozzle

Comment: @0scar: I'm using [AS 755](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/101581/3201), but made a mistake, it's not T8-T9 (I was in the afterburner!), but T5-T8 as you use in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total temperature, denoted as Tt, remains constant throughout the nozzle as it performs no thermodynamic work. In the context of station numbering, the entry point of the nozzle is labeled as station 5 (or 050 according the AS755 *Aircraft Propulsion System Performance Station Designation and Nomenclature* standard), while its exit point is designated as station 8 (or better 080). Consequently, the ratio of the total temperature at station 080 (Tt080) to that at station 050 (Tt050) is equal to 1.0.

$$\frac{Tt_{080}}{Tt_{050}} = 1$$