# How do the contrarotating turbines work in the F-119-PW-100?

Tags: jet-engine, turbofan, turbine, turbojet

I was reading about the F22 Raptor and found out that its powerplants use  contrarotating turbines. How does this work

Also, if the spools and their connected compressors are rotating in opposite directions, won't the stators and their angles and such be different?

And, if it reduces a row of stators then the compressor which acts as a stator in the last stage, how does it change the AOA according to the flow rate, if it works like a stator?

Also, the F119-PW-100 has 3 low pressure compression stages and 6 high pressure ones. Which means it should have 10 stator stages. So, if a row of stators goes away, how many stator stages remain.

I'm sorry if I'm wrong somewhere or I reached conclusions which aren't right. I'm a 16 year old enthusiast, and I'm just curious.

Comment: Related: [How does the Pratt & Whitney F119 achieve its features?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/33456/14897)