# What are the approaches to monetize the external cost of climate change impact on aviation

Tags: environment

I am a student that is graduating university soon. I have an urgent case and I am asking for help from the aviation involved community that is aware of enviromental impact of aviation.

I have started to work on my first-cycle studies thesis and I am having a hard time understanding the core aim of my topic and what it specifically means.
The thesis is "Approaches to monetize the external cost of climate change impact on aviation".

Can anyone here help me with understanding this topic and giving me some tips and the main  topics/aims of chapters that will be needed.

Comment: This question is too broad for a StackExchange site, and likely requires touching on topics brought up in your classes, anyway.

Comment: If you don't understand the core aim of your thesis topic, you should probably go talk to the professor who has assigned you this topic.

Comment: You should show your current state of research about different taxes and fees and asks for specific part of it. Moreover, I think this question is more suited in economical politics than in aviation expert websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more economics than aviation, but let's give it a try.

[External cost](https://market.subwiki.org/wiki/External_cost) means that an activity imposes cost on a party that is not part of that activity. This activity is in your case climate change. That cost is in your case the burdens of climate change on aviation. Since aviation is part of what is affecting the climate, climate change is not a pure externality. The wording of your thesis topic could be improved in my eyes.

To [monetize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monetization) the external cost is simply a way to measure the cost such that it can be expressed as a monetary value. The cost would be:

- More severe weather events which delay flights or cause re-routing.
- Flooding of coastal areas which requires the relocation of low lying airfields, aviation businesses and aircraft factories which are located in soon-to-be-flooded areas.
- Hotter atmosphere which negatively [affects engine efficiency](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1609/why-do-jet-engines-get-better-fuel-efficiency-at-high-altitudes/4983?r=SearchResults&s=10%7C9.4356#4983).

Comment: I truly appriciate your time and help, Sir. The issue is, that  I was concerned that this was connected to something like emission reducement and decarbonization  projects such as CORSIA and emmision taxation or technological advancements that would compensate the level of emmisions. I understood monetization as: gaining benefits; making the reduction of emmision more efficient; collecting money from taxes and investing them into CO2 reduction projects.

Comment: @Georgeb: Indeed, I also first thought this is about letting the aviation industry pay for their part in global warming. But the way the sentence is structured makes that interpretation impossible – except your thesis adviser is a lousy English speaker. You may want to reaffirm the correct interpretation.

Comment: Consider developing a hypotheses statement that can be disproven with data?